# Update panel placed in user control causes full postback

Tags: user-controls, updatepanel, asp.net-4.0

I have a user control. Which contains update panel. I want to update only part of the page for SelectIndexChanged event of radiobutton list, but my update panel causes full post back.
I am using vs-2010.

The hierarchy is as below.
 Master page->.aspx page->user control->user control->update panel

I tried to do this by directly putting user control in .aspx page. In this case it works fine.

My code for HTML mark up is as below.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMedicalStatus" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
             <table class="TABLE100">
                <tr>
                  <td> 1.</td>
                  <td>Diabetes Mellitus</td>
                  <td align="right">
                      <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbDiabetes" runat="server"                                               RepeatDirection="Horizontal"                                       onselectedindexchanged="rdbDiabetes_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                                        AutoPostBack="True">
                         <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                         <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:RadioButtonList>
                  </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
          </ContentTemplate>
           <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdbDiabetes" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        <%--<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="rdbDiabetes" />--%>
           </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
  </tr>
```